# what is the difference between **isolated local minimum** and **local minimum and isolated critical point**?

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

In section four of the paper [On the stable equilibrium points of gradient systems](https://people.montefiore.uliege.be/absil/Publi/stable_minima_SCL0505/stable_minima12.pdf), authors introduce two concepts listed below.

I am confused about the difference between them.

Could anyone help to clarify it? Thanks in advance!

(1) Isolated local minimum

(2) Local minimum and isolated critical point.

They seems the same to me.

Comment: A [critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)) is -as we know- one where the derivative of a function is zero. Does that mean that there is a (local) minimum?

Comment: Can the 'Close' vote be explained?

Comment: Yes. Unless I am missing something it is pretty obvious by looking at the link I provided that a critical point is not a minimum. In particular an isolated critical point is not an isolated local minimum. ( Close votes can be undone by Reopen votes. So please start a fruitful discussion. )